# Save the current page in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I am using VueJS and Vuetify.

In v-data-table UI Component of vuetify, I want to save the current page that the current user is. For example, if the user is on the page 3 of 10, and he reloads the page, it will automatically go back to page 3 of 10. The current function is when the user reloads, it goes back to page 1 of 10.

```js
footerOptions: {
    showFirstLastPage: true,
    showCurrentPage: true,
    itemsPerPageOptions: [20, 50, 100],
    itemsPerPageText: 'Data per Page',
},

getPagination(data) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', data.page)
},
```

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="tableHeaders"
    :items="users"
    item-key="username"
    :loading="isLoading"
    @item-selected="itemSelect"
    @toggle-select-all="selectAll"
    @click:row="singleClick"
    @dblclick:row="doubleClick"
    @pagination="getPagination"
    :footer-props="footerOptions"
    show-select
    multi-sort
    dense>
</v-data-table>
```

Edit: I am already getting the current page and save it to session storage. Now, all I need to make that currentPage binded in the v-data-table. I tried to used the page prop of v-data-table but nothing happens. Still on page 1 even the currentPage is 2/3/4 and so on.

Comment: You need to save the value between refreshes.  web storage, cookies, query params, etc.  see the answers on this post: [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads) for more details

Comment: @yoduh, I think it's different. But I am able to store the current page number to the session storage. My problem now is how to apply the save paged to the v-data-table. I tried to used the page prop but nothing happens.

Comment: I've posted an answer that should hopefully help you

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should try:

1. add `:page` prop on v-data-table to bind the page number to a data property `pageNum`.
2. listen for `update:page` event which fires from v-data-table any time the table's page value changes, then call a method named `pageChange`
3. in the `pageChange` method you should save the page value (passed in for you by the event) to localStorage: `localStorage.setItem("page", newPage);`
4. on component creation, set `pageNum` to the value saved in localStorage: `this.pageNum = localStorage.getItem("page");`

simplified component code shown below:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="tableHeaders"
      :items="users"
      :page="pageNum"
      @update:page="pageChange"
    >
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageNum: 1,
      tableHeaders: [],
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    pageChange(newPage) {
      localStorage.setItem("page", newPage);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.pageNum = localStorage.getItem("page");
  },
};
</script>
```

This will persist the page number value that v-data-table holds across page refreshes.  You might want to think about clearing localStorage, `localStorage.clear();`, when the user navigates to a different page so if they come back to the page with v-data-table they are on page 1 again.

Comment: Thanks for this! We successfully used it. We also improved on it by saving & loading the whole `options` object because then other options like items per page, sorting, and filtering will also be persisted. We only reset the options when the underlying data count changes. Mind: If only `page` is persisted, the visible data might be vastly different because of sorting or especially items per page (as page 5 on 10 per page starts at #41, while page 5 on 5 per page starts at #21)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that your `users` is requested from backend?
You should change the value of `pageNum` binded to `v-data-table` after `users` are got from remote.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :items="users"
    :page="pageNum"
  >
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageNum: 1,
      users: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    getUsers().then((promise)=>{
      this.users = promise.data
      this.pageNum = sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage');
    })
  },
};
</script>
```

The key point is that you should set the value of `pageNum` when `v-data-table` already has multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super simple solution using the power of setup function and VueUse!

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-73536361-pagination-currentpage-vueuse-3yycx0?file=/src/components/Example.vue

[VueUse](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse) is a collection of utility functions based on Composition API. With support for Vue 2 & 3. In this example I'll use the `useStorage` function that simplifies the process to create a reactive LocalStorage/SessionStorage.

1. First, install the VueUse npm package: `npm i @vueuse/core`
2. Then in your vue component import `useStorage` from `@vueuse/core`. And configure your reactive variable in the setup function like this:

```js
<script>
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core'
export default {
   name: 'Example',
   setup() {
      const state = useStorage('my-page', {
         page: 1
      })
      return { state }
   },
   data: () => ({
      ...
   })
}
</script>
```

3. Then in your `v-data-table` get/set the current page with the `page` prop and make sure to use the `.sync` modifier and link it to your reactive variable. In this example `state.page`.

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :page.sync="state.page"
    :footer-props="{
    showFirstLastPage: true,
    showCurrentPage: true,
    :items-per-page="3"
    itemsPerPageOptions: [3, 50, 10],
    itemsPerPageText: 'Data per Page',
    }"
    class="elevation-1"
></v-data-table>
```

4. That's it! VueUse is awesome, you can add more variables to your reactive state to save the items per page or anything you want.

[image]